# Reducing the number of columns using a condition in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a big matrix with more than 1000 rows and 100 columns. In each row ONLY 6-10 columns having values and the rest are zeros. I want to create a matrix has only 5 columns that taking the values of the 5 consecutive columns in each row. For example:

```
A = structure(c(0, 1L, 6L, 0, 2L, 0, 2L, 0, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 0, 3L, 0, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 0, 4L, 6L, 2L, 0, 0, 5L, 0, 3L, 5L, 0, 0, 0, 4L, 6L, 7L, 0, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 0, 0, 8L, 9L, 0, 0, 0, 9L, 1L, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 2L, 7L, 0, 2L, 0, 0, 1L, 8L, 4, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 14L))

#A =
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
#[1,]    0    0    1    2    3    4    5    0    0     6     0     0     7     1
#[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    0    0    7     0     0     0     0     8
#[3,]    6    0    7    0    1    2    3    4    5     0     0     0     2     4
#[4,]    0    1    2    3    4    0    5    6    7     8     9     0     0     0
#[5,]    2    4    6    0    0    0    0    7    8     9     1     2     0     0
```

I want this matrix:

```
B = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 2L), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))


#B = 
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[4,]    5    6    7    8    9
#[5,]    7    8    9    1    2
```

My code:

```
df = data.frame(A)
B = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:NROW(df), function(i) df[i,][(df[i,])!=0][1:5]))
# or
B = t(apply(X = df, MARGIN = 1, function(x) x[x!=0][1:5]))
```

My code works fine for the first two rows of A but fails for the rest of the rows. I also thought about getting the columns indexes that are none zeros and then to see if there are 5 consecutive columns (without any gap between them) and retrieve their values. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What if row doesn't have 5 consecutive values?

Comment: This version also works if a row has no 5 subsequent values (then it prints 5 NAs): `t(apply(A,1,function(z) z[(-4:0)+match(5,Reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(y,x+y,0),z!=0,acc=TRUE))]))`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `rollapply`:

```
library(zoo)
t(apply(A,1,function(x) {x[match(T,rollapply(!!x,5,all)) + (0:4)]}))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [3,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [4,]    5    6    7    8    9
# [5,]    7    8    9    1    2
```

If you have rows without any sequence of 5 it will crash, please update your post if you want it to be handled.

Or the same but prettier:

```
library(purrr)
Adf       <- as.data.frame(t(A)) # data.frame fits more this data conceptually, you have different series, and it's better to put them in columns
res_df  <- map_df(Adf,~ {.x[match(T,rollapply(.x!=0,5,all))+(0:4)]})
res_mat <- as.matrix(t(unname(res_df))) # if you want to go back to ugly :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `rle`

```
t(apply(A, 1, function(x) {
      rl <- rle(x !=0)
    head(x[inverse.rle(within.list(rl, values[!(values & lengths >= 5)] <- FALSE))], 5)}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[4,]    5    6    7    8    9
#[5,]    7    8    9    1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: missed some details, here is my new attempt in using apply and the base library:

```
cumfun <- function(x){           
  y<-ifelse(x>0,1,0)
  tmp<-cumsum(y)
  pos<-which(tmp-cummax((!y)*tmp)==5)
  x[(pos-4) : pos]
}

B<-t(apply(A,1,cumfun))

> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    5    6    7    8    9
[5,]    7    8    9    1    2
```

Comment: Yeah, but the results are not matching

Comment: This is not what OP wants (there have to be 5 non-zero values in a row)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, misread the question. Should be correct now! @PoGibas

Answer (score 0):

```
library(zoo)
t(apply(A, MAR = 1, function(x, n = 5) x[which(rollsum(!!x, n)==n)[1]+seq_len(n)-1]))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    5    6    7    8    9
[5,]    7    8    9    1    2
```